# Facebook like button using XFBML

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm trying to add the like button to a web page using the XFBML method, so that the dialog box shows when the like button is clicked.

I've used the Facebook configurator which generates the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="225" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

However, when I place it in the HTML `body` tag, nothing appears. What am I missing here?

Comment: Anyone care to weigh in here... I've tried every tutorial available and still no luck. Is there a link within the developer docs that can shed some light on this. I'm a noob at this with a client breathing down my neck to get this fixed. Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the official website: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

For the answer, you should use `<div class="fb-like">` instead of `<fb:like>`. For example:

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://yourwebsite.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

The HTML doesnt know what a `<fb:like>`, and you should tell the HTML fb:like is a name of a div.

Does it help?

Comment: This seems to be the "HTML5" method, which appears to be the default (and only) method available now. The "XFBML" version, as mentioned in the question, is no longer an option?